Why doesn't my css work when i change my endpoint (css file location remains the same)
I'm making a Library web using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. The css works fine when the endpoint is 'localhost:8080/Library/write', however when i try to change my endpoint to 'localhost:8080/Library/blogwriting/write', the css doesn't work anymore (js as well), and the browser logs-out errors like restricted MIME type and error 403 on the css file that i try to link to, eventhough i haven't changed its location in my project structure, can anyone explain why, and any solutions that makes css and js work again when i change my endpoint to 'localhost:8080/Library/blogwriting/write'?
My css import:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Project file structure
resources
|_static -> css -> style.css
|_templates -> write.html

Spring Boot Controller
package com.springdemo.library.controller;

import com.springdemo.library.model.Blog;
import com.springdemo.library.model.User;
import com.springdemo.library.repositories.BlogRepository;
import com.springdemo.library.security.userdetails.CustomUserDetails;
import com.springdemo.library.services.GenerateViewService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/blogwriting") //since 'localhost:8080/Library/blogwriting/write' didn't display css, i had to remove the mapping "/blogwriting"
public class BlogWritingController {

    private GenerateViewService generateViewService;
    private BlogRepository blogRepository;

    @GetMapping("/write")
    public ModelAndView blogWriting(Authentication authentication) {
        return new ModelAndView("write");
    }

}

Appreciate your help!

try using "/static/css/style.css" as a route. Hopefully, it will solve the issue.

yeah it works, but i just don't really understand why changing the mapping cause the css to not work, although the css file location aren't changed

Because relative URLs get resolved against the URL of the main document, that you are using them in. In localhost:8080/Library/write, css/style.css will resolve to localhost:8080/Library/css/style.css, whereas in localhost:8080/Library/blogwriting/write it will resolve to localhost:8080/Library/blogwriting/css/style.css
